# How to send url in cleaner way in jquery php?

Tags: php, jquery

Ok i want to send a complete url to a php file which also consists parameters suppose url is like folder/test.php?parm1=19&parm2=119&param3=345.
What iam doing is putting it like this following is pesudocode

```
var urlParameter="urlparameter="+(above url)
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data:urlParameter ,
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

now in some.php when i will access the urlParameter i will not get my complete url i will only get

```
folder/test.php?parm1=19
```

for making complete complete url i have to get the param2 value and param3 and then again form url again this work fine but is there is a better way to send complete url with parameters in jquery?

Comment: I think Muu has correctly answered your question, but what you are describing is a GET, not a POST.  With a POST, your request URL is some.php, but with a GET request, your URL will be some.php?param1=A&param2=B.  You can access these with $_GET or $_POST in PHP, or $_REQUEST if you're not fussed how your request comes in.

Comment: oh sorry get yes you are right i was just putting pseudo code

Comment: @MickSear To me it looks like the OP wants to make a POST request with a URI as one of the parameters. There's nothing wrong with doing this

Comment: @Phil, yes, that's what made me ask the question.  I agree you can do both - it's perfectly valid, but the question wasn't quite clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can do this:

```
data = {
    'param1' : 19,
    'param2' : 119,
    'param3' : 345
}

$.post('/some.php', data, function(msg) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
})
```

Comment: no my url is build like this folder/test.php?parm1=19&parm2=119&param3=345. i want to send it as string

Comment: Try going:  "data: {'data' : urlParameter}" instead of "data:urlParameter".

Answer (score 1):

Use object notation for sending request parameters, eg

```
$.post("some.php", {
    urlParameter: "folder/test.php?parm1=19&parm2=119&param3=345"
}, function(data) {
    // etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the escape method to your string, before sending it and after in your php code, unescape it.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: You should read the page you've linked to; *The escape() function should not be used to encode URIs. Use the encodeURI() function instead.*

Comment: I disagree with you, in his case '?' or '&' or '=' seem to be the problem for getting the data as he wanted.
encodeURI() specifies This function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ # (Use encodeURIComponent() to encode these characters).
So the real method to use is encodeURIComponent() and in his case escape should work.